# GetElementById alternative

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom, curl

I'm trying to code a simple script with curl, but the problem is I need to gather special key that is generated on every new POST request (`onLoad()`). The problem can be easiyle be passed by creating a new DOM element and getting value using GetElementById function from DOM but, in this case, there is no "id" declared in specific tag I want to return value from. There is only a name.

Example:

```
<input name="trans_id" value="Lk+Vz957skV845b7x2DX7iyR1FI=" type="hidden">
```

Bellow there is a pseudo-code I did today (last paragraph is where I need help):

```
<?php
    // Author       :   me
    // Date         :   10.11.2013.
?>

<?php
    // Declaring variables :)
    $data_string = '';
    $url = 'http://www.website.com';
    $uagent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6';

    // Declaring variables for e-pay
    $url2 = 'http:/website2.com';

    ...

    $exChar = '|';
    $exStr = '';

    $exStr = Explode($exChar, $_POST['ccep']); 

    $data = array (
        "email" => '',
            ...
        "submitFromInputForm" => 'Next',
    );

    foreach($data as $key=>$value) { $data_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
    rtrim($data_string, '&');   

    $ch = curl_init ();


    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $uagent);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);



    $result = curl_exec ($ch);
    print($result);

    // ====================================================================
    // Need help with this function
    $check = strpos($result, 'Confirmation');
        if ($check == True) {
            $doc = new DOMDocument();
            @$doc->loadHTML($result);
            $id = $doc->getElementsByName('trans_id');
            echo 'Value:' . $id;
        }
    // ====================================================================    

    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

But to be honest, I wasn't able to get result from that function because, well, it doesn't exsist. Google search only help me with droping results to use getElementsByTagName which after reading documentation from PHP official, does not resolve my problem.

A note at the end: I don't want to include any Javascripting, only pure PHP.

Thank you in advance,
regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DOMXPath` in order to access specific properties by xpath.

```
$domx = new DOMXPath($doc);
$trans_id = $domx->evaluate("//input[contains(@name, 'trans_id')]");
```

Eventually loop through the object if necessary

```
foreach ($trans_id as $id) {
    echo "Value:" . $id->nodeValue;
}
```

---

On second thought, you need the `value` attribute, so you'd need to use `getAttribute()` in order to retrieve it. I just tested with the following code and it works as expected:

```
<?php
$result = '<input name="trans_id" value="Lk+Vz957skV845b7x2DX7iyR1FI=" type="hidden">';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($result);
$domx = new DOMXPath($doc);
$trans_id = $domx->query('//input[@name="trans_id"]');
foreach ($trans_id as $id) {
    echo "Value: " .  $id->getAttribute('value');
}
```

prints:

```
Value: Lk+Vz957skV845b7x2DX7iyR1FI=
```

Comment: Thank you for help @Royal Bg. Unfortunately, seems like your code does not work properly. I tried to extract the first value on which function triggers ($trans_id->item(0)->nodeValue;) but seems that it doesn't work also. Would you mind checking the evaluate expression, it may be wrong. I also tried to use foreach loop but it didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: @HalisDuraki I edited my answer, this should work as expected :)

Comment: Now that works well. Additionally, I didn't need foreach loop so I removed it (there is only one tag named "trans_id") and replaced it with `item(0)`. Answer accepted.